# SyntaxError when trying to use backslash for Windows file path

Tags: python, syntax

I tried to confirm if a file exists using the following line of code:

```
os.path.isfile()
```

But I noticed if back slash is used by copy&paste from Windows OS:

```
os.path.isfile("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx")
```

I got a syntax error: (unicode error) etc etc etc.

When forward slash is used:

```
os.path.isfile("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx")
```

It worked.

Can I please ask why this happened? Even the answer is as simple as :"It is a convention."

Comment: I don't think this should be closed because it's not about an error, it's about why Python handles strings the way it does. Plus one from me.

Comment: It is better to use forward slashes for a [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/) anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backslash is the escape symbol. This should work:

```
os.path.isfile("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\xxx")
```

This works because you escape the escape symbol, and Python passes it as this literal:

```
"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx"
```

But it's better practice and ensures cross-platform compatibility to collect your path segments (perhaps conditionally, based on the platform) like this and use `os.path.join`

```
path_segments = ['/', 'Users', 'xxx', 'Desktop', 'xxx']
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(*path_segments))
```

Should return `True` for your case.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the segmentation strategy. I don't use Python, but I imagine this strategy can apply to most languages.

Answer (score 4):

Because backslashes are escapes in Python. Specifically, you get a **Unicode error** because the `\U` escape means "Unicode character here; next 8 characters are a 32-bit hexadecimal codepoint."

If you use a *raw string,* which treats backslashes as themselves, it should work:

```
os.path.isfile(r"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was wondering why people are using a 'r' as part of argument. Now I now it is "raw string".

Answer (score 3):

You get the problem with the 2 character sequences `\x` and `\U` -- which are python escape codes.  They tell python to interpret the data that comes after them in a special way  (The former inserts bytes and the latter unicode).  You can get around it by using a "raw" string:

```
os.path.isfile(r"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx")
```

or by using forward slashes (as, IIRC, windows will accept either one).

Comment: Thank you very much. I learnt something new from everyone's reply.